# Pyspark Jupyter Notebook: How to write CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([('Tom', 80), ('Alice', 20)], ["name", "height"])
df1 = df.select(df.name).orderBy(df.name.desc())
df1.coalesce(1).write.csv('result315.csv')
```

I received the following error:
Does anyone know how to fix this? I am new to using pyspark and stack overflow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDorP.png)

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 df.coalesce(1).write.csv('D:/NationalData/result316.csv')
>
> ~\Desktop\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py
>   in csv(self, path, mode, compression, sep, quote, escape, header,
>   nullValue, escapeQuotes, quoteAll, dateFormat, timestampFormat,
>   ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace,
>   charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, encoding, emptyValue)
>       930                        charToEscapeQuoteEscaping=charToEscapeQuoteEscaping,
>       931                        encoding=encoding, emptyValue=emptyValue)
>   --> 932         self._jwrite.csv(path)
>       933 
>       934     @since(1.5)
>
> ~\Desktop\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1255         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258     1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> ~\Desktop\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py
>   in deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> ~\Desktop\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       329             else:
>       330                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o906.csv. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 5.0 (TID 16, localhost, executor driver):
>   java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644
>   D:\NationalData\result316.csv_temporary\0_temporary\attempt_20200315131009_0005_m_000000_16\part-00000-4137684d-8b50-47d2-a5de-0fc86db0834f-c000.csv
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.(CSVFileFormat.scala:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
>     ... 33 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command
>   string: null chmod 0644
>   D:\NationalData\result316.csv_temporary\0_temporary\attempt_20200315131009_0005_m_000000_16\part-00000-4137684d-8b50-47d2-a5de-0fc86db0834f-c000.csv
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.(CSVFileFormat.scala:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     ... 1 more

[Error Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDorP.png)

Comment: did you try to use an absolute path to a location where you have write permissions?

Comment: I just tried and received the same error.  I believe I have permissions but do not know how to check. I used D:/NationalData/abstest.csv.

Comment: I can write pandas csv files to that location no problem.

Comment: Edit your question to have the error message and the image displayed.

Comment: I do not know how to display the image but I got the error message.